# javascript toggle function using php variable as id

Tags: javascript, php

This is the toggle function without using a php variable as the div ID. The div ID that will be getting toggled is `div3` in the code below.

```
<script>
 function showFormcaster() { 
       $('#div3').toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Because I am making a status system with many replicated divs I need the `div id` to be unique for each `div` that contains the reply box and submit button. I have decided to use the `id` from the status that will be getting replied to as the `div id` that will get toggled.

This is the div that will get toggled

```
$mail .= '<div id="'.$status_id.'?>" class="replyholder">';
```

below are a few methods I have tried to get this to work

METHOD1:

```
<script>
var show;
show = "'.$status_id.'";

     function showreply() { 
       $(show).toggle();
    }
```

METHOD 2:

```
<script>
 function showreply() { 
       $('#<?php echo $status_id ?>').toggle();
    }
</script>
```

METHOD 3

```
<script>
 function showreply() { 
       $('#<?php $status_id ?>').toggle();
    }
</script>
```

I am not so good at Javascript and most of the time when I come to using it, it is guess work and Google however I can't seem to find an answer and what I have found I have tried.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do and if so do you think you will be able to help me out and solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: How many of those replyholder divs will you have on the page?

Comment: It will depend on how many statuses the user has loaded on there screen. To start with I will probably need about 10 but as I will be adding the load more content js feature when a user hits the bottom of the page there will be another 10 needed and so on until the user stops scrolling down or the statuses runs out

Comment: Okay, so how is `showreply()` called?

Comment: `$mail .= '<button class="replybutton" onclick="showreply();">Open Reply</button>';` That is how I call `showreply()`

Comment: And that always toggles a single replyholder div?

Comment: it toggles the div with the id that the function is called to. Because there are more then 1 div with the same id then it will glitch out and only toggle the top div however if it was to toggle all of the ones with the same id then you will have about 10 reply boxes toggling at the same time what isn't what I need either. I need to set each div with a php id that changes for each status and that is only the status id that makes it unique so I have to use that and trying to get the script to recognize the id variable is what I need to do as I can set it to the div without a problem

Comment: so u have a button for every div and you want to toggle the corresponding div on click?

Comment: Yes. I have a button foreach div, a reply box for each status and everything. I would like to hide the reply box and button for each status by using this toggle method. I can reply to each status and I see replies to each status under the correct status. I am also going to use this feature to hide the replies until someone clicks to see them. This is so I can have my index page really nice and tidy and can load more statuses using less space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html use:

```
<div id="<?= $status_id ?>" class="replyholder">THIS IS THE CONTENT</div>
```

Modify method 1 to this

```
show = '<?= $status_id ?>';
$('#' + show).toggle();
```

and pay attention to # symbol at

```
$('#' + show).toggle();
```

Method 2 looks ok for me, and in method 3 you forgot 
"print" command in php code

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested and I still cannot seem to get it to work. doesn't do anything. I do appologize but i forgot to add the div into the $mail php variable I have now resorted out my original post with the php $mail variable the code with the div inside is this `$mail .= '<div id="'.$status_id.'" class="replyholder">';`

Comment: I deleted the comment I added as I included the wrong `$mail` I have now added the correct one

Comment: Solution is correct in general. Did you debug? Take a look at generated page source. And use FireBug to debug what do you have in "show" variable. And so on...

Comment: ok thank you. I will check it all out then as long as I know it is something going on this end and not within the js script then I should be able to solve the problem. Thank you for your time in answering.

Comment: I have just downloaded firebug and just used it to check. by the looks of it the `<?php $status_id ?>` within `$('#<?php $status_id ?>').toggle();` doesn't seem to process the php variable and comes back as `function showreply() { 
       $('#').toggle();
    }`  The reply system works fine using the `$status_id` variable and I am also include the js script after I am creating the `$status_id`

Comment: The id is being attached to the div as the divs do have different numbers next to them and a database check shows that the correct id is being added to the correct div

Comment: ok so I got it to work now. The only problem is that it takes the id from the last div and uses that so the reply box only shows for the bottom div